# Explicit demonstration of a quantum measurement interaction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

$$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left \langle #1 \right \rvert}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left \rvert #1 \right \rangle}
\newcommand{\braxket}[3]{\left \langle #1 \middle \rvert #2 \middle \rvert #3 \right \rangle}
\newcommand{\expec}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}
$$

As can be verified from my post history, I am just self-studying Ballentine. At any rate, I am stuck on the attached question (Problem 9.4):

[image]

We note from the outset that $c$ is unitless, as is obvious on dimensional grounds.

Suppose we have some initial, unentangled state (we assume pure states). The initial state of the object is some superposition of position states, of course.
$$|\Psi_0\rangle = \ket{\psi_0} \otimes \ket{\alpha},$$
where $\ket{\alpha} = \int dx \, \alpha(x) \ket{x}$ denotes a preparatory state of the apparatus and $\ket{\psi_0} = \int dx\, \psi_0(x) \ket{x}$ is the initial state of the object. We note that the time-development operator is given by
$$U(t) = e^{-i\int dt\, H(t)/\hbar} = e^{-icQ^{(1)}P^{(2)}\int dt\, \delta(t)/\hbar} = e^{-icQ^{(1)}P^{(2)}/\hbar}.$$
We now consider the measurement interaction:
$$\ket{\Psi_0} = \ket{\psi_0} \otimes \ket{\alpha} \to \ket{\Psi_f} = e^{-icQ^{(1)}P^{(2)}/\hbar}\ket{\psi_0} \otimes \ket{\alpha} = \int dx \int dx' \, \psi_0(x) \alpha(x') \left[ e^{-icQ^{(1)}P^{(2)}/\hbar} \ket{x} \otimes \ket{x'} \right]$$
$$ = \int dx \int dx' \, \psi_0(x) \alpha(x') \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \left[(-icQ^{(1)}P^{(2)}/\hbar)^n \ket{x} \otimes \ket{x'} \right]$$
$$= \int dx \int dx' \, \psi_0(x) \alpha(x') \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \left(\frac{-ic}{\hbar} \right)^n  \left((Q^{(1)})^n \ket{x}\right) \otimes \left((P^{(2)})^n \ket{x'}\right) $$
$$= \int dx \int dx' \, \psi_0(x) \alpha(x') \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{-icx}{\hbar} \right)^n \ket{x} \otimes \left((P^{(2)})^n \ket{x'}\right) $$
$$\stackrel{(1)}{=} \int dx \int dx' \, \psi_0(x) \alpha(x') \ket{x} \otimes \left(\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{-icx}{\hbar}P^{(2)} \right)^n \ket{x'}\right)$$
$$ = \int dx \int dx' \, \psi_0(x) \alpha(x') \ket{x} \otimes \left(e^{\frac{-icx}{\hbar}P^{(2)}} \ket{x'}\right)$$
$$ = \int dx\, \psi_0(x)  \ket{x}\otimes \left(\int dx' \, e^{\frac{-icx}{\hbar}P^{(2)}} \ket{x'}\alpha(x')\right)$$
$$ =  \int dx\, \psi_0(x)  \ket{x}\otimes \left(\int dx' \, e^{\frac{-icx}{\hbar}P^{(2)}} \ket{x'}\bra{x'}\ket{\alpha}\right)$$
$$\int dx\, \psi_0(x)  \ket{x}\otimes \left( e^{\frac{-icx}{\hbar}P^{(2)}}\ket{\alpha}\right)$$
$$ \equiv \int dx\, \psi_0(x)  \ket{x}\otimes \left( T^{(2)}(cx)\ket{\alpha}\right),$$
where in (1) we use the linearity of the tensor product and where in the last equality we have identified the translation operator.

Now let's consider computing $\expec{Q^{(1)}Q^{(2)}}$ on the post-interaction state (this expectation value is related to the correlation coefficient and has been the proxy which Ballentine uses for correlation). We obtain
$$\expec{Q^{(1)}Q^{(2)}} = \left[ \int dx'\, \psi^*_0(x')  \bra{x'}\otimes \left( \bra{\alpha}T^{(2)}(-cx')\right)\right]Q^{(1)}Q^{(2)} \left[ \int dx\, \psi_0(x)  \ket{x}\otimes \left( T^{(2)}(cx)\ket{\alpha}\right)\right]$$
$$ \stackrel{(1)}{=} \int dx \, x|\psi^*_0(x)|^2 \bra{\alpha}T^{(2)}(-cx)Q^{(2)}T^{(2)}(cx)\ket{\alpha}$$
where in (1) we've used the inner product definition on a tensor product space and $\braxket{x'}{Q^{(1)}}{x} = x\delta(x-x')$.

But this doesn't seem to be what Ballentine wants in the end. What does he mean by the "value of $Q^{(2)}$"? I also can't see where to go past where I've gotten to.

Any suggestions for continuing this calculation (or a completely different method for solving) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I tried to use \newcommand but it still seems to format weirdly. Can anyone help me fix the formatting? I'm not sure why it's not working after consulting the MathJax documentation.

Comment: So: much to my surprise and for reasons unknown, I manually changed the MathJax commands for your first ket, explicitly using “\vert” and “\rangle” and the other “\ket” commands now display correctly.  I have no idea why this happened or if is this is usual.

Comment: Weird, it still shows all as red and wrong for me? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: PS if you can give me any hints on this problem I'd greatly appreciate it. I guess the message is no exercises questions at all, even if it's not homework? @ZeroTheHero

Comment: yeah it went back to the uncompiled form…